# text view show half of the content in storyboard

Tags: ios

everyone.
  I drag an text view object into a view ,and typing a lot of content.but it only
show a little context. Please see the below screenshots show.why?

[image: text view show]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does't matter. when you're running the app in the simulator or hardware, it will show all content. :)